# build cordova with command line in cygwin

Tags: android, cordova, cygwin

I am using cygwin to build the cordova android project.

I created a project successfully
but there is some errors when I build it:

```
╭─Dozer@Dozer-PC  ~/Projects/ba-crm/crm-plus  ‹master*›
╰─$ cordova build                                                                                               127 ↵
Running command: cmd args=["/c","C:\\cygwin64\\home\\Dozer\\Projects\\ba-crm\\crm-plus\\platforms\\android\\cordova\\build"]
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
```

But I have already install all the libraries in cygwin:

```
╭─Dozer@Dozer-PC  ~/Projects/ba-crm/crm-plus  ‹master*›
╰─$ ant -version                                                                                                  
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
╭─Dozer@Dozer-PC  ~/Projects/ba-crm/crm-plus  ‹master*›
╰─$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
╭─Dozer@Dozer-PC  ~/Projects/ba-crm/crm-plus  ‹master*›
╰─$ cordova -version
3.4.0-0.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because the library is installed does not necessarily mean that the environment variable is set.  To see if it's set, in Cygwin I believe you can do `echo "$ANT_HOME"`.

Additionally as the error says, make sure it's set correctly.  For example, on my machine `ANT_HOME` points to `C:\Source\ANT\apache-ant-1.8.4`.

Lastly, make sure your path is set up to have `%ANT_HOME%\bin`

Comment: I use the on my zsh too,and I set the environment variable in `~/.zshrc`.I set the ANT_HOME like cygwin style `/cygdrive/c/ant`, when I change it to windows style like thie `c:\ant`, it works well. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

export ANT_HOME=c:/path/apache-ant-1.9.4
(export ANT_HOME/cygdrive/c/path/apache-ant-1.9.4 fails - you need the :/ style)